# Console Pasting Newlines Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In pycharm version 2017.2.3, when you copy from console and paste in console, it generates a new line. How to disable that?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from answers [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205990864-PyCharm-2016-3-console-pasting-newlines):

1.Settings

2) Keymap

3) Search in keymap: "Copy as Plain Text"

4) Right click and add keyboard shortcut

5) Fill in with Ctrl+C

6) Answer: "remove" if prompted on already mapped key